# Why I can't upload file and send some other parameters with content-type of multipart/form-data when I'm using nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, file-upload, multipartform-data, nginx-reverse-proxy

I need to upload a file with some other string type parameters, the content-type is multipart/form-data.And now the problem is I can make it with postman when I run my application locally,but when I put my program to my server which has the nginx reverse proxy I can't upload my file.The response is 502 bad gateway or 400 bad request.I don't know why , does the problem from the nginx?

I try to add the nginx upload module to the nginx,but I don't know how,and I want to find some other solutions.I guess not every application need the upload module of nginx if it has the ability to reveive the file by itself,am I right? But I think I still need to do some configuration with the nginx proxy. By the way ,both my application and nginx are run in docker.

This is the method to receive the file and other parameters:

```
[HttpPost, Route("addbook")]
public ActionResult AddBook() {
            IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files["bookcover"];
            //process the file...

            Book book = new Book {
                BookID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                Name = Request.Form["bookName"],
                Author = Request.Form["bookAuthor"],
                OwnerID = Request.Form["ownerid"],
                Introduce = Request.Form["bookIntro"],
                UploadTime = DateTime.Now,
                BookCover = filename
            };
            db.Insertable(book).ExecuteCommand();
            return Ok("success");
        }
```

Can I successfully upload the file without using nginx upload module and how?
Thanks for help.
Frank.

Comment: To check whether it is related with file upload, I suggest you try to remove the parameter for file, will this issue exist? If you enable stdout log, is there any detail error message?

Comment: I try to remove the file parameter and left other string type parameters, but I still can't access the method, I got "400 bad request".
I can access other method except this one , the different between this method and others is this method use content type: multipart/form-data.

Comment: Please share us full controller code, and `Startup.cs`. A mini demo to reproduce your issue would be helpful

Comment: My full controller would be too long to paste here , so I push my code to the github:https://github.com/Frankane/WechatServer/tree/signalR, I would appreciate it if you have time to watch them. The related controller is BookController, and I also put my nginx.conf there too.

Comment: The related method in BookController is AddBook().

Comment: I solved my problem , but stll thanks for help. The solution I got is change the proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade" to proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection in nginx.conf file.

Comment: @FrankKane Have you got any solutions?